# PHP: How can I put HTML Code with PHP Code within into a PHP Variable?

Tags: php, html, variables

I have a question about `"` and `'` in PHP. I have to put a complete `<li>` element into a PHP variable but this doesn't work, the output is completely false...

```
    $list = 
"
    <li class=\"<?php if($info[1] < 700) {echo \"half\";} else {echo \"full\";} ?>\">

        <div class=\"onet-display\">

        <?php if ($image = $post->get('image.src')): ?>
            <a class=\"onet-display-block\" href=\"<?= $view->url('@blog/id', ['id' => $post->id]) ?>\"><img class=\"onet-thumb\" src=\"<?= $image ?>\" alt=\"<?= $post->get('image.alt') ?>\"></a>
        <?php endif ?>

        <h1 class=\"onet-thumb-title\"><a href=\"<?= $view->url('@blog/id', ['id' => $post->id]) ?>\"><?= $post->title ?></a></h1>
        <div class=\"uk-margin\"><?= $post->excerpt ?: $post->content ?></div>

        </div>

    </li>
";
```

Is it because there is PHP Content in the HTML Code? How can I solve this?

Can someone help me and explain why this doesn't work?

Comment: Instead try using heredoc and nowdoc syntaxes. It would be better for such situations

Comment: you can't put <?php inside php code

Comment: You chose the wrong approach. Storing such content does not make much sense. You do _not_ want such content inside a variable, since there you cannot do anything with it. So the question is: _why_ did you put it there? What were you trying to do? If you told us, _then_ we would be able to help and point out better approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `<?php ... <?php`

Since your string contains PHP tags, I suppose you expect them to be evaluated. The opening PHP tag within another PHP tag is interpreted as a part of the PHP code. For example, the following outputs `<?php echo time();`:

```
<?php echo "<?php echo time();";
```

There are several ways to build a PHP string from PHP expressions.

#### Concatenation

You can create functions returning strings and concatenate the calls to them with other strings:

```
function some_function() {
  return time();
}

$html = "<li " . some_function() . ">";
```

or use `sprintf`:

```
$html = sprintf('<li %s>', some_function());
```

#### eval

Another way is to use [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php), but I wouldn't recommend it as it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code and may cause unexpected behavior.

#### Output Buffering

If you are running PHP as a template engine, you can use the [output control functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php), e.g.:

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>

<li data-time="<?= time() ?>"> ...</li>

<?php
$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo $html;
```

*Output*

```
<li data-time="1483433793"> ...</li>
```

#### Here Document Syntax

If, however, the string is supposed to be assigned as is, use the [here document syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

```
$html = <<<'HTML'
<li data-time="{$variable_will_NOT_be_parsed}">...</li>
HTML;
```

or

```
$html = <<<HTML
<li data-time="{$variable_WILL_be_parsed}">...</li>
HTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

**You want to store some html into a variable.**

Your source should (if not yet) start with

```
<?php
```

Then you start building the contents of `$list`.

Starting from your code the nearest fix is to build `$list` by appending strings:

```
<?php
$list = "<li class=";

if($info[1] < 700)
{
    $list .= "\"half\"";  // RESULT: <li class="half"
}
else
{
    $list .= "\"full\"";  // RESULT: <li class="full"
}

// ...and so on...
```

Now a couple things to note:

`$list .= "...` is a short form of `$list = $list . "...`

Where the `.` dot operator joins two strings.

Second thing **you may make code easier to read by mixing single and double quotes**:

Use double quotes in PHP and single quotes in the generated HTML:

```
<?php
$list = "<li class=";

if($info[1] < 700)
{
    $list .= "'half'";  // RESULT: <li class='half'
}
else
{
    $list .= "'full'";    // RESULT: <li class='full'
}

// ...and so on...
```

This way you don't need to escape every double quote

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to work like this

```
$test = "PHP Text";

$list = "<strong>here ist Html</strong>" . $test . "<br />";  
echo $list;
```